# Can't use Textbox in Webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control and the user can navigate to various sites.
But after setting the address

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(Address)​
```

I can't use any textbox. All the buttons and links work as usual though.

EDIT:
By saying "i cant use" i mean no interaction is possible. I can't enter any test nor paste anything into them

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Currently your question lacks information, could you please edit it and include a more thorough description of the problem? For instance, what do you mean by that you _"can't use any textbox"_? Can't you write/interact with them at all? Ensure that you don't make any infinite loops, or set the textboxes' `Enabled` property to false.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of your textbox.
The `ReadOnly` property has to be set to `False` and the `Enabled` property needs to be `True`.
If it still doesn't work:
Can you interact with the textbox before navigating to the address? If yes, check for possible unwanted actions concerning the textbox in the WebBrowser1.Navigating Event, if you have one.